# How to fix this string format in iOS?

Tags: ios, parsing, nsstring

Im parsing a string which is normall in this format:

> 8:00AM - 9:00PM

I use this code to separate opening from closing time and I get an array of 2 times:

```
NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    int idx = [s rangeOfCharacterFromSet:digits].location;
    NSString *timeStr = [s substringFromIndex:idx];
    NSArray *timeStringsArray2 = [timeStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
    NSLog(@"timeStringsArray2 %@", timeStringsArray2);
```

The issue is that some timestrings are written incorrectly like this:

> 8:00AM- 9:00PM

This simple error throws an error of:

```
-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Because its not being able to separate the items in the timestring.  Im sure that even if I have the client fix these errors, they will at some time reinsert a record with this error again.  How can I account for both scenarios?

Comment: couldn't you just separate by `@"-"` (without the spaces on either side of the dash)? or remove the extra whitespace in the timestring (i.e. to get rid of the spaces completely)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of problem that regular expressions were made for.

The code below will split a string `timeString` into two separate times `firstTime` and `secondTime` in the cases you describe, whether written correctly or incorrectly. It will  cope with more than one space, no spaces, or any whitespace characters instead of spaces, making it a little more robust than just assuming you have a maximum of one space either side of the dash:

```
NSString *timeString = @"8:00AM - 9:00PM";

NSString *pattern = @"\\s*-\\s*";//Matches zero or more whitespace characters surrounding a dash character

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:0 error:NULL];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:timeString
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [timeString length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSString* firstTime = [timeString substringToIndex:matchRange.location];
    NSString* secondTime = [timeString substringFromIndex:matchRange.location + matchRange.length];

    NSLog(@"First time: %@", firstTime);
    NSLog(@"Second time: %@", secondTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While we are at it - don't rely on whitespace being here and there! To fix your code, just remove all whitespace first, then separate by the hyphen (without the spaces, again):

```
NSString *timeStr = @"8:00AM- 9:00PM";
NSString *stripped = [timeStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSArray *times = [stripped componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I don't know how to make your code work, but I just tested the way I would do it:

```
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"8:00AM - 9:00PM", @"*"];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:testString];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -"]];
NSString *startTime = nil, *endTime = nil;
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"-" intoString:&startTime] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"*" intoString:&endTime]) {
    // Process the row as needed.
    NSLog(@"Start time:%@, End time:%@", startTime, endTime);
}
```

which correctly produces the output:

2013-08-11 00:29:20.665 StackOverflowTests[15213:c07] Start time:8:00AM , End time:9:00PM

It also produces the exact same result with 8:00AM- 9:00PM so I hope that helps.